# Elements In Table Moving When Text Added to Label

Tags: jquery, css, razor

I have a table on a cshtml page:

```
                 <table>
                    <tr><td><label>Upload File:</label></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="choose" value="Choose File" onclick="document.getElementById('file_upload').click();" />
                            <input type="file" class="form-control no-border" style="display:none;" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" onchange="addNew()" />
                        </td>
                        <td><label src="" id="file_upload_lbl" class="fileLabel" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="button" class="fbtn btn-custom btn-primary" onclick="submitFile(); return false;" value="submit" /></td></tr>
                </table>
```

So the choose button is clicked, it opens a file chooser. When a file is chosen, it sets the text of the label 'file_upload_lbl' with the file name using juery:

```
    function addNew() {
        var file = document.getElementById('file_upload').files[0];
        if (file != null) {
            $("#file_upload_lbl").text(file.name);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when the label text is set, it moves both the "Choose" and "Submit" buttons up about 5px, so the label and button are no longer aligned.

Is it because of the hidden file chooser? It shouldn't be, as style="display:none;" is supposed to ensure it takes up no space on the page. Is it because adding text is removing the css of the label? It doesn't move or change size, it seems like the buttons are moving...

Here's the css

```
    .fileLabel {
        border: 1px solid;
        width:400px;
        height:27px;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are including jquery with some other jquery files like jquery ui etc , It may cause this.without any extra package it works fine.

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
      integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script>
      function addNew() {
        var file = document.getElementById("file_upload").files[0];
        if (file != null) {
          $("#file_upload_lbl").text(file.name);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      .fileLabel {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 400px;
        height: 27px;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr
        ><td><label>Upload File:</label></td></tr
      >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input
            type="button"
            id="choose"
            value="Choose File"
            onclick="document.getElementById('file_upload').click();"
          />
          <input
            type="file"
            class="form-control no-border"
            style="display: none"
            id="file_upload"
            name="file_upload"
            onchange="addNew()"
          />
        </td>
        <td><label src="" id="file_upload_lbl" class="fileLabel"></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr
        ><td
          ><input
            type="button"
            class="fbtn btn-custom btn-primary"
            onclick="submitFile(); return false;"
            value="submit" /></td
      ></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <html>
```